# Carbon footprint calculation for my cluster in Google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have stupid question in mind for sometime. I should better ask on this community.

Is it possible to calculate the carbon emission for my cluster which is on Google cloud platform? I am using spark cluster using google dataproc.

As of my technical discussion depends mainly on cost and i would like to include carbon emission as another parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain it will provide enough detail for your needs, but the following site gives details on Google's environmental efforts: http://www.google.com/green/

In particular, this whitepaper discusses Google's carbon offset purchasing http://www.google.com/green/bigpicture/#/offsets/whitepaper

In terms of DC efficiency, Google publishes this site with details of Google's power usage in DCs: http://www.google.com/green/efficiency/datacenters/

Answer (score 0):

I saw a calculator on LinkedIn but I can't find it now.

But Google has disclosed the emissions on https://cloud.google.com/sustainability/region-carbon

If you are based in Europe and/or can live with the latency `europe-west6` has the lowest Grid carbon intensity.